# Copy resource file in Output directory during installation

Tags: c#, winforms, resources

I am using Windows Form 3.5. i have an image box in a form. I bind the image from the `project/resources.res x`

[image]

however i want to copy my resource file in the output directory during installation. so that i can change the resource file in the installation directory.

I am not sure if i am thinking right or is there any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the resource file to output directory simply by selecting `copy always` in the `copy to output directory` property in the `property window` of the `resources.resx` file.